# Why do my functions keep reading input from my input text field?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, input

The input on my html form has a problem. Curently I am taking the input which is a twitter name into an Ajax function that calls tweets via php from the twitter api. 
As I have a setInterval function to keep checking for updates, the input is passed again and again into the function to get tweets.

The problem is that the function seems to be reading the input directly from what is in the text input box. So if the user changes the text without pressing enter or hitting the button, the function keeps reading that text as the input. So the input entered initially is not fixed after pressing enter or hitting the button to submit.

Here is the html form taking in the input:

```
<div id="topdiv">Input Twitter ID: <input type="text" id="userid"    onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===13) {document.getElementById('tweet-button').click();}">  
<input type="submit" id="tweet-button" onclick="getStatusesX();" value="Get recent tweets">   
<p id="tweetbox"></p>
</div>
```

Here are the functions:

```
function getStatusesX() {

   var userID = document.getElementById("userid").value;
   getStatuses(userID);
   var intervalstop = setInterval(function() {getStatuses(userID);}, 20000);
   clearInterval(intervalstop);}

//Create a cross-browser XMLHttp Request object
function getXMLHttp() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        XMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    return XMLHttp;
}

//function that searches for the tweets  via php
function getStatuses(userID){

XMLHttp1 = getXMLHttp();

    //ajax call to a php file that will extract the tweets
    XMLHttp1.open( 'GET', 'TwitterGlimpsePHP.php?userid='userID, true);

    // Process the data when the ajax object changes its state
    XMLHttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( XMLHttp1.readyState == 4 ) {
            if( XMLHttp1.status ==200 ) {  //no problem has been detected
                document.getElementById("tweetbox").innerHTML=XMLHttp1.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    XMLHttp1.send(null);
}
```

I want the input to be taken as the text after enter is pressed. I have tried assigning it to variables but cannot work out why it keeps reading from the input field. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could it be because you are setting an interval call to getStatuses and therefor each time that would call, it would be re-executing the code therefore taking the text from the input box each time.

Comment: You can disable the input or something...in the way you have your function, you just need one click to invoke it n-times

Comment: So every time your user clicks enter or submits the query it compounds the interval? You should assign that as a var and clearInterval(var) in your getStatusesX function

Comment: @KaiQing I adjusted the getStatusesX function above. Is this how you meant to do it?

Comment: no i mean declare the var outside the function and clear interval inside it. javascript can access vars outside function so you don't have to worry about scope there.

Comment: @KaiQing declare the userID var outside the function? Then just call clearInterval(userID); inside the function?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer...

Comment: @KaiQing Sorry, I'm a novice, just learning, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an official answer - just trying to clear up my comments

This is what I mean by declaring outside the function...

```
var intervalstop;

function getStatusesX() {
   clearInterval(intervalstop);

   var userID = document.getElementById("userid").value;
   getStatuses(userID);
   intervalstop = setInterval(function() {getStatuses(userID);}, 20000);

}
```

that way you initialize the var and inside the function you clear first to ensure it's not compounding. Then you set the var to a new interval to begin again.

You said twitter doesn't like something about this code if the user clicks many times - Makes perfect sense. They will want to throttle the API to prevent someone from making 50,000 requests per minute cause of improper coding. You should check the API specs to make sure you're within a realistic zone and consider caching the results locally if you are pushing boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are re-reading the value of the textbox every time getStatuses is called.

Try capturing the value of the textbox first, and passing it into your getStatuses function:

So your new getStatusesX is:

```
function getStatusesX() {
    var userID = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    getStatuses(userID);
    setInterval(function() {
        getStatuses(userID);
    }, 20000);
}
```

Update getStatuses to take a userID parameter and delete the line where you're reading the textbox's value inside of getStatuses.

That having been said, it might be an issue if this is possible to begin with - what if the user clicks the button to automatically refresh statuses multiple times? You might want to disable the button/textbox after it's been clicked, or have it clearInterval the old interval first.

Comment: I have edited my code above to what you suggested. It wasn't executing the getStatusesX() after i applied the changes.

Comment: actually its fine, just mixing up my java and javascript syntax. Unfortunately I have a problem now when the button or enter has been clicked multiple times. Twitter didn't like that. Thanks for the help.